# Return all values contains a specific text from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, regex

How to return all values contains a specific text/string from a list as a comma separate value?

i have a list of emails like this:

```
emails = ['email@example.com',
'email1@example.com',
'email2@example.com',
'emaila@emailexample.com',
'emailb@emailexample.com',
'email33@examplex.com',
'emailas44@exampley.com',
'emailoi45@exampley.com',
'emailgh@exampley.com']
```

what i want to do is get all emails from the same domain like this:

```
Website = 'example.com'
Email = 'email@example.com','email1@example.com','email2@example.com'
```

and so on....

i tried this so far but can not figure out how can i achieve this, would be great if anyone help me, thanks in advance.

```
def Email(values, search):
    for i in values:
        if search in i:
            return i
    return None

data = Email(emails, 'example.com')
print(data)
```

Comment: `[email for email in emails if email.endswith('@' + Website)]`?

Comment: @jdehesa thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning value at the first iteration itself that's why you are not able to achieve the result. You can store the emails in a `list` and then return the comma separated values.

Modifying your approach:

```
def Email(values, search):
    x = list()
    for i in values:
        if i.endswith("@" + search):
             x.append(i)
    return ", ".join(x) # Returning list as a comma separated value

emails = ["email@example.com","email1@example.com","email2@example.com","emaila@emailexample.com","emailb@emailexample.com","email33@examplex.com","emailas44@exampley.com","emailoi45@exampley.com","emailgh@exampley.com"]
website = 'example.com'

data = Email(emails, website)
print("Website = " + website)
print("Email = " + data)
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Answer (score 2):

You never needed a regex. Use a list-comprehension taking advantage of `str.endswith()` to look for strings with matching characters towards the end:

```
emails = ['email@example.com',
          'email1@example.com',
          'email2@example.com',
          'emaila@emailexample.com',
          'emailb@emailexample.com',
          'email33@examplex.com',
          'emailas44@exampley.com',
          'emailoi45@exampley.com',
          'emailgh@exampley.com'] 
Website = 'example.com'

print([email for email in emails if email.endswith(f'@{Website}')])
# ['email@example.com', 'email1@example.com', 'email2@example.com']
```